# Как получить цвет фона в PictureBox в C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как получить цвет фона в PictureBox в C#

Answer (score 3):

Используйте свойство [BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx):

> Получает или задает цвет фона для элемента управления.

```
   Color color = control.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

var color = pictureBox1.BackColor;